# Real world examples of complex probability?

Tags: probability, complex-numbers, markov-chains

Stochastic systems can be modeled with a matrix where the sum of each column is one. For example a coin toss can be represented like this
\begin{bmatrix}
    0.5       & 0.5 \\
    0.5       & 0.5 \\
\end{bmatrix}

Another way is to let the transition probabilities be complex numbers. The interpretation of something happening is the euclidean norm squared. Also, the transition matrix should be orthogonal for powers to make sense.

For example, let's look at a magical coin

\begin{bmatrix}
    \frac{1}{\sqrt2}       & -\frac{1}{\sqrt2}  \\
    \frac{1}{\sqrt2}        & \frac{1}{\sqrt2}  \\
\end{bmatrix}

When you toss it once, it acts like a regular coin. When you toss it twice, it's guaranteed to land on the opposite side. When you toss it three times, it again acts like a regular coin. When you toss it four times, it's guaranteed to land on the same side.

And so on, repeating the pattern.

These kind of systems are closely related with quantum mechanics but is there any meaningful real-world examples that can be modeled with them?

Comment: The entire real world is made of quantum mechanics!

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I imagine it's probably safe to assume that by "real-world", OP probably means "familiar". Though the choice of phrase is certainly amusing.

Comment: Can't you achieve this behaviour with regular Markov chains ?